# MySQL tables better to have data in one table or two table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

Hello I am developing a small app in cakephp. I am using Auth component for user login.

Each user will have profile.
Each user will go under any role of "Admin" or "Starter" or "Pro"

I have users table and user_roles table.

For profile should I create another table "profiles" or I can just create fields in users table? Which query works faster? Two table or one table

Also Should i really need a user_roles table or I can just assign roles in the adding user form code? Hard code or in the database with foregin key in users table?

Any advises appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For profile, if the same user can have create different profiles, you should create a different table, otherwise just have them in one table. It looks more organized to have it in different table, but its not necessary.

For user_roles, if a user can have multiple roles, have them in different tables, otherwise you can put it in the same table.

A single table is slightly faster than multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to have multiple roles/profiles, you should have a second table to identify them.

In the case you know for sure you will only give one role per user, you can have a second table, but you may want do it in another column of the user's table.